# How can I delete a realm parent object along with all of its child objects?

Tags: swift, realm, tableview

```
class Days : Object {
        @objc dynamic var weekday : String = ""

        let workout = List<Workouts>()
    }

class Workouts : Object {
    @objc dynamic var title : String = ""
    var parentDay = LinkingObjects(fromType: Days.self, property: "workout")

    let exercise = List<Exercises>()
}

class Exercises : Object {
    @objc dynamic var exerciseName : String = ""

    var parentWorkout = LinkingObjects(fromType: Workouts.self, property: "exercise")

    let wsr = List<WeightSetsReps>()
}

class WeightSetsReps : Object {
    @objc dynamic var weight = 0
    @objc dynamic var reps = 0
    var parentExercise = LinkingObjects(fromType: Exercises.self, property: "wsr")
}





 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            if editingStyle == .delete {
                try! realm.write {

                    if days?[indexPath.section].workout[indexPath.row].exercise[indexPath.row] != nil {
                        realm.delete(((days?[indexPath.section].workout[indexPath.row].exercise[indexPath.row].wsr)!))
                        realm.delete(((days?[indexPath.section].workout[indexPath.row].exercise)!))
                        realm.delete((days?[indexPath.section].workout[indexPath.row])!)
                    } else {
                        realm.delete((days?[indexPath.section].workout[indexPath.row])!)
                    }


                    tableView.beginUpdates()

                    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

                    if days?[indexPath.section].workout.isEmpty == true {
                        realm.delete((days?[indexPath.section])!)
                        let indexSet = IndexSet(arrayLiteral: indexPath.section)
                        tableView.deleteSections(indexSet, with: .automatic)
                    }

                    tableView.endUpdates()
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to delete the parent object along with all of its related child objects upon execution of `swipeToDelete`.

The way it's set up right now, when there are multiple child objects in the parent object, and I swipe to delete that parent object, only one of the child objects get deleted.

How can I delete all of the child objects?

Comment: Realm doesn't offer a cascading delete for this use case. So, you'll need to get the parent object, delete the child objects and then delete the parent. It's not clear what the actual structure is from the question so it's hard to be specific but that's the general practice. If that doesn't answer the question, update it with your models so we can see what the relationship is between parent and child objects. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay Thanks. Sorry for not including enough detail. I updated my answer to include 
 the data model. I'm relatively new to Swift and programming so I'm still figuring things out as I go. What you're suggesting is kind of what I attempted to do here. I'm just not sure how I should go about deleting multiple exercises within each workout. Do I have to use for loops or is there a more practical way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has numerous answers; from reading in the workouts from the Days' List object and iterating over them to delete each one - to - querying for the days matching workouts and then delete

Let's do a query. Realm objects are lazily loaded so if there's 10 or 10,000, the memory impact will be minimal and will avoid an iteration loop would could slow the UI.

The first thing to note is there's an inverse relationship between Days and their parent Workout objects.

We can leverage that relationship to select which workouts belong to which days and then delete them.

The second thing is that realm.delete can be passed a single object to delete or a *sequence of objects*.

Here's the code. I don't know which day and workouts objects you want to delete, so I am going to delete the workouts that go with the first day object.

```
if let day = realm.objects(Days.self).first {
    let thisDaysWorkouts = realm.objects(Workouts.self).filter("ANY parentDay == %@", day)
    try! realm.write {
        realm.delete(thisDaysWorkouts)
    }
}
```

Once those are deleted, you can delete the parent object.

Note that Realm doesn't currently have cascading delete's.

As an unrelated side note, you may want to consider giving your objects [Primary Keys](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys). It will help with organization in the long run as the project grows.